# NameError: name 'labels_true' is not defined for dbscan

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I am using a template script and trying to feed in my data. However, I am not sure what labels_true implies as the error states that is it undefined.

Here is my data array:

```
data=array([[5.71585827e+00, 3.32320000e+04],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       ...,
       [9.57746479e-02, 3.40000000e+01],
       [7.01388889e-01, 1.01000000e+02],
       [9.70350404e-02, 3.60000000e+01]])
```

Now I am applying this script:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


# #############################################################################

X=data
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

# #############################################################################
# Compute DBSCAN
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit(X)
labels = db.labels_ 

print("Homogeneity: %0.3f" % metrics.homogeneity_score(labels_true, labels))


NameError: name 'labels_true' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.homogeneity_score.html) on scikit-learn `homogeneity_score` (emphasis added):

> Homogeneity metric of a cluster labeling **given a ground truth**.

where `labels_true` are

> ground truth class labels to be used as a reference

So, *if you already have the ground truth*, that would be the `labels_true` argument, which would be compared with your predicted `labels` to give the score.

Here the error is obviously because you have not provided such a ground truth in `labels_true`, and the variable is not defined, as the error says.

It comes as a direct consequence that, if the ground truth is not available, the metric cannot be used.